# Select fourth div in row, remove margin

Tags: css, css-selectors

Let's say I have 860px width area, where I need put 4 divs (200px width) and 3 spaces beetween them (20px).
If there would be only 4 divs at all, I can use

```
.div {width:200px; margin-right:20px}
.div:last-child {margin-right:20px;}
```

But there can be any number of divs, but only for comes to one line, so I can't use last-child. But width of one line is always 860px.

How to remove margin-right from fourth div in line? Or how to make this spacing correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are targeting every 4th `div` element, you need to use `nth-of-type` with an expression of `(4n+4)` so it will select every 4th element.

```
div:nth-of-type(4n+4) {
    color: red;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gfLPG/)

> Note: Am using a general element selector here, so you need to add a
>   `.` before the `div` as you are using a class named `.div`

Comment: why not nth child why nth of type? this works too http://jsbin.com/olofug/1/edit

Comment: @user1721135 `nth-of-type` and `nth-child` have different meanings, if you've have an element other than `div` `nth-child` will select that, here it will select the element which is `div` in this case, you can say it's like a specific selection, `nth-child` is loose one

Answer (score 0):

This

```
.div:nth-child(4){margin-right:0px;}
```

should work.

But I think you could simply do:

```
.div{margin-left:20px;}
.div:first-child{margin-left:0px;}
```

Because the first element will never change.

Answer (score 0):

So what you need is a grid system, use nth-child:

```
div{margin-left:20px;}
div:nth-child(3n+1) {
margin-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mr. Alien has given a best answer. But in your case you can do like this also (as if of your full width)

```
<div id="main">
<div>one</div>
<div>two</div>
<div>three</div>
<div>four</div>
<div>five</div>
<div>six</div>
</div>
```

when you give margin-right to  `#main > div` the last one is also have margin,

so alternatively you could do

`#main{margin-right: -10px; /*what margin you have given to #main > div */}`

Answer (score -1):

Someone has posted answer with this

```
.div + .div{margin-left:20px;}
```

but deleted it. 
It works for me and looks nice. Is it correct way to do this?

Comment: This selector will select adjacent div means every 2nd div where op wants to select every 4th div

Comment: Not the down voter and you welcome :)